# How to type emdash in Windows Server Core 2019

Tags: windows-server

My question is not about Windows Server with GUI, This question is non-GUI, so what unicodes I should type, I don't know

Comment: Are you just trying to type this into the command prompt? PowerShell? Or what? Please edit your post to make it more clear the circumstances you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

Alt+0151 is the ANSI code & worked to type it in Win10 command-prompt, not sure if it'll work for you. If you have a Windows PC the Character Map program is helpful for this too:
[image]

Source ['googling em dash ansi'](https://www.google.com/search?q=em%20dash%20ansi). [Here is a StackOverflow Q&A on that character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10357622/whats-the-ascii-character-code-for)

Comment: OP @NewbieJavaProgrammer please upvote (up arrow) answers you find useful or hit Accept to those solving your issue. This gives credit to those of us trying to help